# Bring Rechargeable Li-ion battery to shipping mode by using TI library

Tags: battery, texas-instruments, smbus

Search for the right SMBus command, word to write and target address, in order to bring the rechargeable Li-ion battery to shipping mode by using TI (Texas Instruments) library.

The following VB code snippet is broken, i.e. it's unable to bring the battery to shipping mode. It used to work for the older version of rechargeable Li-ion battery.

`AxBq80xRW1.WriteSMBusWord(59, 21316, &H17)`

This VB function uses the function WriteSMBusWord in TI library object AxBq80xRW1, device command is 59, write word 21316 to the device and H17 as object address